# Using RegisterClientScriptBlock to call JavaScript function from WebControl

Tags: javascript, asp.net, svg

I am creating a website using ASP.

I have a web control with an SVG image embedded on it.

```
<embed id="InletsComponent" class="InletsComponent" src="../images/svg/Inlets.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="430px" height="200"px/>
```

On the web control I also have a button.

```
<input id="Button3" type="button" value="3 into 2" onclick="return ConfigureInlets()" />
```

The javascript function is:

```
function ConfigureInlets() {

document.querySelector(".InletsComponent").getSVGDocument().querySelector(".InletsComponentImage").getElementById("I1IN").setAttribute("visibility", "visible");
return;
}
```

Which basically makes one of the svg elements visible.

The above code works fine.

I now want to extend the code so that instead of the button calling the function I can call the function from the server side. (the reason for this isn't obvious from the example, but basically I want to show and hide svg elements based on a number of checkbox states. It is easier to process all this on the server side and then call the javascript to update the image on the client.).

I have added a RegisterClientScriptBlock to my server side code

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Key", "ConfigureInlets()", true);
```

The javascript function is being called, but I am getting the following error:

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'getSVGDocument': object is null or undefined

I believe that this function is being called at a different level to when the button press is calling it. i.e it is being called at the page level and not the web control level. But I am not really sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

try to use jquery to run this function when the document is ready

this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Key", "$(function () {ConfigureInlets()});", true);

or use RegisterStartupScript instead of RegisterClientScriptBlock

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your message. I tried the RegisterStartupScript, but

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your message. I tried the RegisterStartupScript, and I now get a different error: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Member not found. If I do: document.querySelector(".InletsComponent").setAttribute("width", "22"); it works. If I break down what I am trying to achieve into:var a = document.querySelector(".InletsComponent").getSVGDocument(); I get the member not found error. So it does not seem to be able to call the getSVGDocument function (do I need to cast it some how?). I also tried using jQuery but this didn't work either. Any ideas.